# EC2 m1.Medium instance type states the Instance Storage to be 410GB

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I launch the instance, it automatically comes with a 30GB "C: Drive" and some "Ephemeral" drives.

My question is
"...where is the expected 410GB hard drive?"

I noticed you can change the default 30GB to be some other size.
Is this where one can increase to up to 410GB?

Answer (score 2):

Instance storage is not enabled by default:

> Instances that use Amazon EBS for the root device do not, by default,
>   have instance store available at boot time. Also, you can't attach
>   instance store volumes after you've launched an instance. Therefore,
>   if you want your Amazon EBS-backed instance to use instance store
>   volumes, you must specify them using a block device mapping when you
>   create your AMI or launch your instance.

You will find this quote and more info about how to enable it in the [AWS-EC2 User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#InstanceStore_UsageScenarios). See the section "*Making Instance Stores Available on Your Instances*".